# Prove $133\mid \left(11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}\right)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove $133\mid \left(11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}\right)$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer.

So, I went about proving this using Fermat's theorem. 
So I had $11^{n}\cdot 11^2+(12^2)^n= 0\ (\mod 133)$
then $11^n\cdot 11^2+1728^n=0\ (\mod133)$ 
and finally $1^n+132^n=0\ (\mod 133)$. 
Then I said $133^n=0\ (\mod133)$ because $133$ raised to any power will have a remainder of $0$. Did I apply Fermat's theorem correctly?

Comment: Parentheses missing?  Is this $133\, |\, \left(11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}\right)$?  If so, please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: I am unable to do exponents for some reason, but yes that is my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show that $11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}$ is divisible by $133$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150979/show-that-11n1122n-1-is-divisible-by-133)

Comment: @Ayman **Not a  dupe** of that since that one restricts to *inductive* proofs. Please be more careful.

Comment: @BillDubuque Still useful to reference the other question here.

Comment: @Ayman But now most likely it will be wrongly closed as a dupe of that.

Comment: @BillDubuque Retracted the vote for now. Still, I think the questions should be linked eventually.

Comment: You have to specify the exact conditions in which you want the statement to be true. The statement as stated would normally imply that $n\in\mathbb R$ or even $n\in\mathbb C$ (though usually the former one).

Comment: was my method incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Notice $\ 133 =  11^2\!+\!11\!+1\ $ so we may apply

**Lemma** $ \bmod\ a^2\!+a+1\!:\,\ b := a^{n+2}\!+(a\!+\!1)^{2n+1}\!\equiv 0\,$ in any ring, $ $ for all $\,n\in\Bbb Z$

${\bf Proof}\,\ {\rm Note\ that}\ \  \color{#0a0}{a(a\!+\!1)\equiv -1}$ and $\,\color{#c00}{a^3\equiv 1}\ $ by $\,0\equiv (a\!-\!1)(a^2\!+a+1) = a^3\!-1,\,$ so

$\ a^{2n+1}b\, =\, a^{3n+3}\! + (\color{#0c0}{a(a\!+\!1)})^{2n+1} \equiv\, (\color{#c00}{a^3})^{n+1}\!-1\equiv 0\ $ so $\ b\equiv 0,\,$ by $\,a$  $\rm\color{#c00}{unit}$ so cancellable.

---

**Or** use $\ \color{#90f}{a\!+\!1}\equiv -a^2\,\Rightarrow\, (\color{#90f}{a\!+\!1})^{2n+1}\equiv -a^{4n+2}\equiv -(\color{#c00}{a^3})^n a^{n+2}\equiv -a^{n+2}$

**Remark** $ $ Both are essentially special cases of the method used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217567/242), which is a special case of the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242).

Comment: This idea is in one of my old answers, but it wil be hard to find by search.

Comment: You should specify the conditions under which your shown equivalences hold. E.g., $n$ is a non-negative integer.

Comment: @mathh The tag is elem-number-theory so that should be clear.

Comment: The tag shows that the variables being used are most likely of a similar to the 'integer' type. It does not, however, determine the sign of the variables - they are often able to be negative in many problems.

Comment: @mathh Actually the proof works fine for negative $\,n\,$ too if you interpret the assertion of the Lemma as a modular congruence.

Comment: I couldn't find the old answer I had in mind, but I did find [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/185575/242) which is similar (same problem, with similar solution).

Comment: @user26486 I edited the answer so your above comments are now obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

See that $12^2 = 144 \equiv 11 \pmod{133}.$

So we have

$$11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1} \equiv 121(11)^n +12(144)^n $$

$$\equiv 121(11)^n  +12(11)^n \equiv 133(11)^n \equiv 0 \pmod{133}.$$

Answer (score 1):

since $133=7*19$, first show that $$7\, |\, \left(11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}\right)$$
then $$19\, |\, \left(11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}\right)$$

Since $gcd(7,19)=1$, the result follows.
$$ 11^{n+2}\equiv 11^{n}\cdot 11^2\equiv 2\cdot11^{n}\bmod 7$$
$$12^{2n+1}\equiv 5\cdot 144^{n}\equiv 5\cdot 11^{n}\bmod 7$$
So $$11^{n+1} + 12^{2n+1}  \equiv 7\cdot11^n\equiv 0 \bmod 7$$
$$..........................................................................$$
$$11^{n+2}\equiv 121\cdot 11^n\equiv 7\cdot11^{n}\bmod 19$$
$$12^{2n+1}\equiv 12\cdot 144^{n}\equiv 12\cdot 11^{n}\bmod 19$$
So
$$11^{n+1} + 12^{2n+1}  \equiv 19\cdot11^n\equiv 0 \bmod 19$$